# passenger: Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Trying to run `passenger-install-apache2-module` which exits with error message:

```
Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.

Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

I am not running it via sudo command. RVM is installed globally in `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`. I'm on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating Ruby environment with rvm did the trick.

Comment: Must have been something like `rvm use --default 2.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the mentioned `rvmsudo`.

I would check first of all whether your RVM installation is valid and functional.

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling with this for quite some time I switched from rvm to rbenv and this completely cleared up. My theory is that my system ruby@2.4.1 was somehow being invoked by passenger instead of the ruby I wanted to use @2.4.4 and rbenv just doesn't have this issue.